# Ubuntu boots immediately

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, grub

After using Wubi for a few weeks, I thought it would be time to do a real install of Ubuntu. I downloaded the iso file from the official website and installed the iso on a usb (with Pen Drive Linux's USB Installer). Next, I boot my PC via the usb and installed ubuntu on a new partition and also created a swap partition.

When I restart my PC it immediately boots up with Ubuntu without asking for the choice of Ubuntu/Windows7. The files saved under W7 are still available and also Windows is still on the ssd.

In the print screen one can find the current partitions of my ssd. sda1 is the partition where W7 is installed, sda2 is the partitions where W7 saves images and documents, sda3 is the partitions for Ubuntu and sda4 is the swap partition for Ubuntu.

I would like to have a choice to boot Ubuntu or W7. The difference with similar questions is that it will boot immediately Ubuntu and not Windows 7. Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image: Overview of partititions on SSD]

When I use the live boot of Ubuntu and then follow the steps described at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair I get the following (see printscreen).

[image: boot-repair]
[image: boot-repair2]

Comment: Have you followed these steps in this link to run `boot-repair`? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Not yet, thanks for the comment. I will follow these steps now and post the result asap.

Comment: Awesome. Let me know and I will post it as my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: what's the output of `sudo update-grub` and `cat /etc/default/grub`?

Comment: @Braiam, what do you mean by the output? Is sudo update-grub a command or a program.

Comment: If you run a sudo update-grub, you are updating the program grub (the boot-loader), but sometimes with dual boots you need to repair the grub first

Comment: I just ran the boot-repair from the first comment. However, I couldn't click on next since 'grub is still present'. I don't know what this means and Ubuntu is still immediately booting.

Comment: Do you have an Ubuntu live CD you can use, you will need to boot into an Ubuntu Live CD to follow those instructions if you haven't already

Comment: I have an usb with Ubuntu and another usb with the iso of boot-repair (downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) which is installed with UnetBootin.

Comment: Ok So what you will need to do is boot into the USB with ubuntu on it and click on the option try Ubuntu. From there you will simply need to follow the instructions via the command line.

Comment: What happens if you boot with the shift key pressed?

Comment: @celtschk, when I boot with the shift key pressed nothing changed and just Ubuntu boot up. You meant shift without usb? 

I have updated my orginal post and added a new printscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows) you should try running from the terminal

```
sudo os-prober
sudo update-grub
```

The first one will search in all partitions for other operating systems beside ubuntu, and make the system aware of it, the second one re-creates the menu at boot with the entries from known operating systems

Comment: Great! When I boot my pc I get several options with among others Ubuntu and WD7.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the partition? Did you create it in windows? Current Linuxes always give you options of installing side by side with windows or completely replacing windows - which one did you choose?

1. If you have created windows backup disk or have windows original disc then try repairing and installing Linux again and this time choose the proper option of side by side.
2. Use a bootloader/boot manager software in Linux and try looking if the windows boot information comes up.

Comment: I did my best to offer some suggestions to clear up your post, but I still find it very difficult to understand some of what you said; consider expanding on your solution and making your post overall more clear.

Comment: I created an unallocated space on the ssd via Windows. Then I boot the live version of Ubuntu and I have used GParted to create two partitions. Then I installed Ubuntu via the live boot of Ubuntu on the partition. The choice to install Ubuntu next to WD7 wasn't shown and I read in other topics that I had to choice 'use other' and allocated the partitions manually.